# Python Short Url expander

Tags: python, url

i have a problem with expanding short URLs, since not all i work with use the same redirection:

the idea is to expand shortened urls: here a few examples of short url --> Final url. I need a function to get the shorten url and return the expanded url

http://chollo.to/675za --> http://www.elcorteingles.es/limite-48-horas/equipaje/?sorting=priceAsc&aff_id=2118094&dclid=COvjy8Xrz9UCFeMi0wod4ZULuw

So fa i have something semi working, it fails in the some of the abobe examples

```
import requests
import httplib
import urlparse


def unshorten_url(url):
try:

parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
h = httplib.HTTPConnection(parsed.netloc)
h.request('HEAD', parsed.path)
response = h.getresponse()

if response.status / 100 == 3 and response.getheader('Location'):
url = requests.get(response.getheader('Location')).url
print url
return url

else:
url = requests.get(url).url
print url
return url


except Exception as e:
print(e)
```

Comment: What error you are getting with above example?

Comment: https://murphy.rs/nikola/flask-url-shortener

Comment: i get an intermediate web http://web.epartner.es/click3.aspx?ref=754218&site=14010&type=text&tnb=39&diurl=https%3A%2F%2Fad.doubleclick.net%2Fddm%2Fclk%2F302111021%3B129203261%3By%3Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.elcorteingles.es%2Flimite-48-horas%2Fequipaje%2F%3Fsorting%3DpriceAsc%26aff_id%3D2118094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected redirect does not appear to be [well-formed](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L703) according to `requests`:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://chollo.to/675za')
for resp in response.history:
    print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
print(response.url)
print(response.is_redirect)
```

Output:

```
301 http://chollo.to/675za
http://web.epartner.es/click.asp?ref=754218&site=14010&type=text&tnb=39&diurl=https%3A%2F%2Fad.doubleclick.net%2Fddm%2Fclk%2F302111021%3B129203261%3By%3Fhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.elcorteingles.es%2Flimite-48-horas%2Fequipaje%2F%3Fsorting%3DpriceAsc%26aff_id%3D2118094
False
```

This is likely intentional by *epartner* or *doubleclick*. For these types of nested urls you would need an extra step like:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
# from urllib import unquote # python2

# if response.url.count('http') > 1:
url = 'http' + response.url.split('http')[-1]
unquote(url)

# http://www.elcorteingles.es/limite-48-horas/equipaje/?sorting=priceAsc&aff_id=2118094
```

Note: by doing this you might be avoiding intended ad revenues.

Comment: It just a wow solution. So short and easy - Bravo.
import requests
short_url = 'hwll.co/sa8wn'
answer = requests.get(f'http://{short_url}')
answer.url